# Get EC Private Key PEM string from SecKey Object

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get a PEM encoded key from a SecKey on iOS. The EC private key is stored on the Keychain.

I'm getting a Data object from the SecKey object:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        if let cfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(key, &error) {
            return cfdata as Data
        }
    }
```

The Data object is in the **04 || X || Y || K** format. How do I convert that to a PEM key?

Answer (score 0):

Which curve do you use?
if you use kSecECCurveSecp256r1 and kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave, you can't export the ECPrivateKey! Keys created within a trusted coprocessor cannot he exported (and I believe ones imported can’t either). Plus, you should never transfer private key material. It defeats the entire point of the SEP.
see:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrtokenidsecureenclave
https://support.apple.com/en-ng/guide/security/sec59b0b31ff/web